# SPARK: parse each RDD element with a function of a "not serializable"object

Tags: scala, serialization, apache-spark

I am reading a large CSV file in Spark and I would like to parse each line using the CSVParser library (au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVParser)

Here is my code:

```
val parsedLines = sc.textFile("path/to/a/csv/file.csv").map(line => {
     val parser = new CSVParser(',')
     try{
       parser.parseLine(line)
     }catch{
       case e: Exception => "Error"
     }
})
```

The result of calling `parser.parseLine(line)` is an `Array[String]`.

I couldn't create the parser outside the map because the class CSVParser is not serializable.

Is it acceptable to call `new CSVParser(',')` inside the map function as I did in the code above?... if yes, why?... if no, why?

Does `new CSVParser(',')` being called for each element of the RDD?

Is there any more efficient way to do the same processing differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would simply use the `spark-csv` package from Databricks to parse the CSV file, but if you insist on `CSVParser`, you should do a `mapPartitions` instead of a `map`. When you use `map` the `new CSVParser()`is indeed called for each element in the RDD, whereas if you use `mapPartitions` it is only call once per partition.

Comment: Thanks Glennie, for the mapPartitions :)

Comment: here is an example I found for this https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2014/06/19/optimize-map-performamce-with-mappartitions/

Answer (score 0):

var parser = new CSVParser(',');

you can define a function as below and call..

```
 private def getTokens(value: String): Array[String] = {
    if (!"".equals(value)) {
      var tokens: Array[String] = parser.parseLine(value);
        return tokens;
    }
    return null;
}
```